# Set focus on part of sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a big sheet with lot of info, and it raise every day, and i only input new info, so i wanna ask - is a way to set focus on first blank row at opening sheet? (sorry for my bad english, it's not my native lang)

Comment: Can I ask you about `set focus on first blank row at opening sheet`? 1. Which sheet name do you want to focus? 2. In this case, what column in the row do you want to activate? 3. When do you want to move to the cell? For example, it's when the Spreadsheet is opened?

Comment: i have 4 sheets in work, each day, when i open a sheet, i need to scroll, scroll and scroll to reach blank row, so i look for solution do not scroll many times :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you wanted to run the script when the Spreadsheet is opened. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the answers for "1. Which sheet name do you want to focus?" and "2. In this case, what column in the row do you want to activate?". I apologize for this.

Comment: There is four sheets, like "spot1", "spot2", "spot3" and "spot4", and i use rows from A to L.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Script-based Solution:

Since you are open to using Google Apps Script anyway, you can use this simple trigger to set the active cell to the first blank row upon opening the sheet:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var c = 0;
  while ( values[c] && values[c][0] != "" ) { c++; }
  sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(c+1,1));
}
```

### Sample:

[image]

### Reference:

[Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Answer (score 0):

You can add links on top of your sheet. These links will move you to where you want.

For example - if you want to get to the last row, you should:

```
=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rVi631pl-VeskPv7jkk5XRixaQ2UkFSAJwteI-JdoGk/edit#gid=0&range=A"&MATCH(MAX(A1:A),A1:A,1),"go down")
```

In other words:

```
=hyperlink("[link to your actual sheet]&range=A"&MATCH(MAX(A1:A),A1:A,1),"go down")
```

Match formula finds last row and adds this number to your link.

[image]

You can try it here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rVi631pl-VeskPv7jkk5XRixaQ2UkFSAJwteI-JdoGk/edit#gid=0

Does it help?

Comment: Not sure, can it be converted in google script?
Like
function onOpen() {
select(' "A"&MATCH(MAX(A1:A),A1:A,1) ');} <-- really not sure about correct syntax or command